# Getting Illegal character in path at index 53 in POST Request

Tags: jmeter, urlencode

I am trying to POST HTTP request and request is not going thru.  what am I doing wrong or missing?

I think it does not like this part 
colonoscopy.jpg/1-1?

```
Server name: ${hostName} 
Path:  ${virtualDirectory}/data/media/${location}/colonoscopy.jpg/1-1?&prodName=${prodName}&otherParams=&sid=${authToken}

HTTP Header Manager
Content-Type application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Getting

```
Thread Name: Thread Group 1-1
Sample Start: 2019-02-01 15:39:06 PST
Load time: 0
Connect Time: 0
Latency: 0
Size in bytes: 1681
Sent bytes:0
Headers size in bytes: 0
Body size in bytes: 1681
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 1
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""): text
Response code: Non HTTP response code: java.net.URISyntaxException
Response message: Non HTTP response message: Illegal character in path at index 53: http://10.188.169.185/api/v2/data/media/dc2e83cfe2054
Server:%20Microsoft-IIS/10.0
Set-Cookie:%20ASP.NET_SessionId=5cwq0inclxwvmd0qlnd01yo3;%20path=/;%20HttpOnly
X-AspNet-Version:%204.0.30319
X-Powered-By:%20ASP.NET
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:%20*
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:%20Content-Type,Authorization
Access-Control-Expose-Headers:%20Content-Location,%20Location
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:%20GET,%20POST,%20OPTIONS,%20DELETE
Date:%20Fri,%2001%20Feb%202019%2023:39:05%20GMT
Content-Length:%200
colonoscopy.jpg/1-1?&prodName=test&otherParams=&sid=ca1bc7a576a44d9b8270b7cac2dddab8

HTTPSampleResult fields:
ContentType: 
DataEncoding: null
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspect your URL along with the [query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) using [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener, the error can have only one reason: you're sending a character which requires [URL encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string#URL_encoding) as it is.

The reasons are in:

1. One of your variables (`${location}`, `${prodName}` or `${authToken}`) has the character which requires the URL encoding. If this is the case - you will need to wrap it into [__urlencode() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__urlencode)
2. One of your Variables (`${location}`, `${prodName}` or `${authToken}`) is not getting resolved into the value and curly braces characters (`{` and `}`) are not allowed in the URL string without encoding. Use [Debug Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) to make sure that :

   - all the variables have their values
   - all the [characters which require the encoding](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) are encoded using the `__urlencode()` function